# Decompress tgz files using Ant

Tags: ant, build

How do we decompress TGZ file with Ant on Windows machine? I have been trying:

```
<gunzip  src="${ARTIFACT}/${platform}.tgz"/> 
<untar src="${ARTIFACT}/${platform}.tar" dest="${InstallDir}.${LICLIENT_VERSION}.test"/>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<target name="unpack">
    <untar src="test.tar.gz" dest="test" compression="gzip"/>
</target>
```